# C# finding a chronological low to high

Tags: c#, stock

I am analyzing some stock data and I am trying to find a low to high delta chronologically. If you look at the (terrible) picture below what I am looking for is the spread between the 95 and 105 data points.

I am not sure of what the technical term for that would be. They are not the high or the low for the day (intraday high and low). However, it is the lowest value in a day or time period where there is a positive high after it.

I have been trying to figure out a way to do it and I end up with a bunch of circular nested statements that brute force the solution and it's still not doing what I am looking for.

Are there any library's out there or known methods I could piggyback off of?

[image: Poorly Drawn Chart]

I have been using a method where I have a high and low variable and a high and low time and moving through the data one by one. When there is a new lowest low or highest high I set the variables. Then I tried creating an array of high/low/time and every time I find a new high/low I store it. At the end I go back and try and choose the best one based on logic. But I am not happy with it. Seems very poor execution.

Regards

Comment: You are looking for the points where the slope is changing direction (1st derivative).  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative and https://brilliant.org/wiki/derivative-by-first-principle/

Comment: @jdweng perfect thank you if memory servers Math.net has a function for that.

Comment: You're going to find, though, that noise in the data will show up in your derivative. You may need to perform some filtering. This is not unlike peak-detection on any signal. Stock prices aren't nice lines like in your image.

Comment: @Steve no they are not.    I am wondering if what I was doing might end up getting a better end result.  I just found it to be very inelegant.

Comment: I think you need to clearly determine the range in the X axis to consider. Take for example your graphic: why not consider 100? Or the high peak after 95? Or the low peak before 105? Or 80? Related to this you have to determine the level of granularity. If those lines were actually tiny saws, what's the exact logic to ignore them? PS: Paint tip: hold SHIFT to create perfectly horizontal/vertical/45° lines.

Comment: Thinking of stock curves,  you'll probably need multiple steps to get to a result that's useful to you. Just taking the 0- crossings of the 1. Derivative will be _very_ noisy there. So you probably will need to apply smoothing and filtering but without knowing your exact goal, it's hard to suggest any.

Comment: I am not sure I have an exact goal.  Rather I am trying to test a hypothesis.   I suppose what I’m looking at is trying to determine the maximum potential or maximum delta for a given time frame and see what effect it has on the future time frame(based on historic data)

Comment: @Masoric, then why not simply check the data using a determined time-window, and store the max and min values? For example, look for max&min from 09:00 to 10:00, then from 09:05 to 10:05, etc. Of course you shouldn't delete and reload all the data, but instead use like a circular queue, where after each cycle you remove the older 5 minutes and add newer 5 minutes.

Comment: @Andrew.  It is one of the methods I have been playing with.  I am currently looking at storing every example of positive volatility in a time frame.  Once I have that I am going to see what I can do with that data.

Comment: I ended up going with my original method to find maximum positive volatility.     I have the bar data in a data table and crawl through it one row at a time.      The first entry all variables are set to that price.    As we move forward in time I validate if price is higher or lower then the current low/high and set as appropriate.   Every time there is a new lowest low I create a new entry in a list listing the last high low spread, their times, prices, price change, etc.   Then I find the greatest period of positive volatility and write that to my report.